# Downloads multiple images in the same time, and update the list view

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an application in  android that will get the latest news from a server service and then display in a list view. The code is as follows:

```
HomeFragment.java

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    EditText search;
    ImageButton btn;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private NewsHomeAdapter customNewsHomeAdapter;

    Context homeFragmentContext;

    final ArrayList<NewsItem> news_home_data = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();

    // child categories JSONArray
    JSONArray newsItems = null;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        homeFragmentContext = container.getContext();
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.news_home_list);
        search = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    String query_text = search.getText().toString().trim();

                    try {
                        query_text = URLEncoder.encode(query_text, "utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                    }
                    String full_query = query_text;

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    Intent bussiness = new Intent(homeFragmentContext,
                            SearchNews.class);
                    Bundle basket_buss_category = new Bundle();

                    basket_buss_category.putString("SEARCH", full_query);
                    ;

                    bussiness.putExtras(basket_buss_category);

                    startActivity(bussiness);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });

        new GetNewsData().execute(TimeUtils.NEWS_HOME_URL);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                Intent cluster = new Intent(homeFragmentContext, NewsCluster.class);

                Bundle newslist = new Bundle();
                newslist.putString("NLIST",news_home_data.get(position).getCluster());
                cluster.putExtras(newslist);
                startActivity(cluster);


            }

        });

        btn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String query_text = search.getText().toString().trim();
                if (query_text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                    search.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

                else {

                    try {
                        query_text = URLEncoder.encode(query_text, "utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String full_query = query_text;

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    Intent bussiness = new Intent(homeFragmentContext, SearchNews.class);
                    Bundle basket_buss_category = new Bundle();

                    basket_buss_category.putString("SEARCH", full_query);

                    bussiness.putExtras(basket_buss_category);

                    startActivity(bussiness);

                }

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private class GetNewsData extends
    AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<NewsItem>> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    // shfaq Progress Dialogun, deri ne momentin qe te loadohen te
    // dheant
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(homeFragmentContext);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<NewsItem> doInBackground(String... URL) {

    String categories_url = URL[0];
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    newsItems = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(categories_url);
    Log.e("lsbsfbsfdbsfd", newsItems.toString());
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < newsItems.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = newsItems.getJSONObject(i);

            Log.e("po fillo procesimin e ", String.valueOf(i));
            String tittle = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_TITLE);
            String desc = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_DESC);
            String source = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_SOURCE);
            String id = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_ID);
            String link = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_LINK);
            String published_time = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_PUB_TIME);
            String image_url = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
            String newsList = c.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_CLUSTER);
            // download the image;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;


             try { // Download Image from URL 
                 InputStream input = new
              java.net.URL(image_url) .openStream(); // Decode Bitmap

              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); } catch
              (Exception e) {

              }


            news_home_data.add(new NewsItem(tittle, desc, source, id,
                    link, published_time, bitmap,newsList));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return news_home_data;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsItem> news_home_data) {
    customNewsHomeAdapter = new NewsHomeAdapter(homeFragmentContext,
            news_home_data);
    listView.setAdapter(customNewsHomeAdapter);
    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

The adapter is like below.

```
NesHomeAdapter.java

package com.dev.apk.time.al;

public class NewsHomeAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<NewsItem> news_data;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public NewsHomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsItem> news_data) {
        this.news_data = news_data;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return news_data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return news_data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_home_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tittle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
            holder.source = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.source);
            holder.published_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.published_time);
            holder.news_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tittle.setText(((NewsItem) news_data.get(position)).getTittle());
        holder.source.setText(((NewsItem) news_data.get(position)).getSource());
        holder.published_time.setText(((NewsItem) news_data.get(position)).getPublishedTime());
        holder.news_image.setImageBitmap(((NewsItem) news_data.get(position)).getImage());


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
         ImageView news_image;
         TextView tittle;
         TextView source;
         TextView published_time;

    }       
}
```

As you I have a custom listview. For each row I have an image, which is downloaded base on an  URL that comes from JSON. But I have have at minimum 40 news items at the first time, meaning 40 images. It takes too much time to display the news.

Can anybody help me how to download the images in the same time, and then update the listView, or is there a way to display the news , title, description etc, and later updates the images?

Comment: Try to use AndroidQuery for that,See here https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this library [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

by calling

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(yourImageView, "http://example.com/image.png", R.drawable.your_loading_image);
```

in your adapter, 
it will create the list first and download the images later, when the image is downloading, it will show your_loading_image, and the downloaded image will be shown shortly

edit:
to be precise, the Image returned by yout getImage() function in the class NewsItem should be a String url to your image, and replace this line

```
holder.news_image.setImageBitmap(((NewsItem) news_data.get(position)).getImage());
```

to

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.news_image, news_data.get(position).getImage(), R.drawable.your_loading_image);
```

i've met this problem too, and UrlImageViewHelper is the easiest approach to solve this, just import the library and use one line and you get what you want, no need to define your own AsyncTask as the library itself using AsyncTask to load the images

Comment: it gives me an error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError . This has to do with the way I imported it or with the library itself.

Comment: @xhulio koush already provided a jar library file for UrlImageViewHelper (check the description in github link, you'll find the jar download link), you only have to add the jar in your project build path

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using `AsyncTask` in Android. Please have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

This will help you run in the background and Publish your progress or downloaded image onto the imageview.

```
new AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>(){
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String...arg){
   //download the image against the url, and run in the background as not on UI thread.
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
    //Load the imageview with the downloaded image.
}

}.execute(url1,url2,url3);
```